# Spring Integration (HTTP in/outbound gateway) Vs Spring Data REST

Tags: spring, rest

What is the difference in exposing the REST API via., Spring Data REST & Spring Integration API (Spring In/Outbound HTTP Gateway)?

Can give some example in situations where each of them is applicable?

Answer (score 0):

These projects aim different goals:

Spring Data REST

> The goal of the Spring Data REST project is to provide a solid foundation on which to expose CRUD operations to your JPA Repository-managed entities using plain HTTP REST semantics.

Spring Integration

> Spring Integration enables lightweight messaging within Spring-based applications and supports integration with external systems via declarative adapters.

And Spring Integration HTTP Adapters are just bridges between HTTP and the downstream Messaging.

Having the Spring Data REST auto-generation nature I even not sure that you will be able to integrate both instruments. Although I'm sure we can hook into Spring Data REST many ways to send some Messages to the Spring Integration flow. E.g. using [Events](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#events).